# Stop Audio in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, audio

I am using the background video option in Divi (by elegant themes) in Wordpress to show a 4 minute or so long video in the background. The thing is, I don't want the audio. I understand if you scroll down far enough the entire thing stops, but I just don't need or want the audio. Is there any custom code that I can use (or a plugin) to get the audio to stop playing ON THE VIDEO BACKGROUND, or will I have to convert it to a gif? Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide site URL?

Comment: Just decided to scrap the idea of video background, thanks for your help though.